# Install Tomcat7 on Windows Azure and connect to sql azure

Tags: azure, tomcat7, azure-sql-database

Hi I am trying to install tomcat 7 on WA. When I have no configuratiions in the server.xml file the installation goes well but when I add follwoing resource element to server.xml it failes to have a deployment for the HostedService it says "Waiting for Instance" and then aborts it and begins again.
I am using eclipse and a worker role. this is the element which make it fail.

```
<Resource
        name="jdbc/myname"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="**@**"
        password="****"
        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://*****.database.windows.net:1433;database=EmoteDB1;user=***@***;password=*****;encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="10"
        maxWait="5000"
        jmxEnabled="true"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="20"
        logAbandoned="true"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        validationQuery="select 1"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="3600000"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000"
        numTestsPerEvictionRun="10"
        testWhileIdle="true"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        testOnReturn="false"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on above, configuration you may need to add proper TCP/IP port in your configuration to get SQL Database connection working. Can you RDP to Azure VM and check if connection to SQL Database is working on not. I believe the problem is processing the XML in Tomcat start phase and you may not have configured proper port in Azure VM for SQL Database connection.

If you can not RDP to Azure VM, I have done exact same configuration in past and following are the steps I used.

After I deployed Tomcat7 to Azure VM through a worker role, I RDP to Azure VM and then configured the SQL Database connection manually in the Azure VM. And this is mostly done by modifying server.xml and adding SQL drivers to the tomcat installation. Once all setup is done and configured working, I copied that back to my desktop and build the full SQL Database supported Tomcat setup and put together in my Windows Azure Worker Role along with proper TCP/IP endpoint configuration to get it working.

Comment: Thank you I have added proper tcp port to in my server.xml file. How do I add installation of Sql Driver to my worker Role so that it will be installed automaticaly when your recycle the instance of the worker role?

Comment: They exact same way you have done on your local machine while you are connected with Azure VM over RD.